# Why do my web apps look different when they're being viewed on a phone?

Tags: html, css, iphone, web

#### [Link to app](https://lucid-bhabha-c258c1.netlify.app/)

I've written the media queries to make the app responsive and they looked fine when I'm viewing them via Chrome DevTools. First screenshot is from Chrome DevTools, second is from my iPhone X:

[image: App viewed from Chrome DevTools]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iphone X has a screen size of 325x812, which is the first difference.

Secondly, G Chrome Dev is an **emulator**, which means it only simulates what a page will look like on a specific device. It does not account for hardware and software (say which browser you're using). They use different rendering engines, so deviations are bound to occur.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the URL, you are using react to make your page responsive which takes care of your application to be visualize properly on all the screen size.

You have design correctly only, you don't want your users to open desktop view in mobile.